# Wordpress - Access Wp Object in Array and retrieve all ids

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I've created a query getting only some users with specific criteria. I store these users into an array. My problem is to get back from this array only specific values like ids.

I `print_r` my function `myfriends()` and I get something like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => WP_User Object ( 
            [data] => stdClass Object ( 
                [ID] => 48 
                ) 
            ) 
        [1] => WP_User Object ( 
            [data] => stdClass Object ( 
                [ID] => 47 
                ) 
            ) 
    ) 
[1] => 
)
```

)

I need to retrieve all the ids of users in array so I've tried with:

```
$myfriends = myfriends($user_id); //good

$myfriendsids = $myfriends->ID; //not working
$myfriendsids = $myfriends[0]->ID; //not working
$myfriendsids = $myfriends[0][0]->ID; //not working
$myfriendsids = $myfriends[0][0][0]->ID; //only the first user id!

//even tried
$myuserdata = $myfriends->data; //not working
$myuserids = $myuserdata->ID; //not working
```

How can I get all the user ids I have?
NB. "not working" means that I `print_r` all the variables and I get nothing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking a bit I've accessed and stored ids values with a `foreach` loop in `$myfriendsids`. Cool.